# Count number of rows in a column including blank cells

Tags: microsoft-excel

I'd like to know the current endpoint of a particular column which may include blank cells.

For example, the endpoint of column B is row 3:

```
     |   A    |  B  | C |
 1   | Foo    | 2.5 |   |
 2   | Bar    |     |   |
 3   | Baz    | 2.3 |   |
 4   | Foobar |     |   |
 5   | Barbaz |     |   |
```

Normally, I'd try `COUNT(B:B)` but this excludes blank cells.

Comment: Do you really need to use `B:B` or `$B$1:$B$5` is fine for you?

Comment: @Vylix No it doesn't need to be an indefinite length (`B:B`).

Comment: What do you expect of the result? `2.3` ? Row number `3` ? `B3` ?

Comment: @Vylix I'd expect the answer 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the last *(bottom)*, use:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(MAX((ROW(B:B))*(B:B<>"")))
```

This works for both numbers and text in column **B**

Comment: What alchemy is this?! Amazing. It works. Care to explain how?

Comment: @LondonRob  It creates an array of row numbers that do not contain *Null* ...and returns the max of that array.

Comment: Does this work if there is a header?

Comment: @Vylix  it should work